# Rmarkdown Error when Knitting - Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called 'bookdown'

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to knit an Rmd file and for some reason, when I knit, RStudio is giving me the following error:

Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called 'bookdown'
Calls:  ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted

Here are my setup chunks:

````r
```{r, echo=F}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(eval=TRUE,echo=T,warning=F,message=F,cache=F, include =TRUE)
```

```{r}
# Install and upload the following packages
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")
library("sqldf")
library("data. Table")
library("reshape")
```
````

This doesn't make sense to me because "bookdown" is not a package that I am trying to use or install anywhere and I don't believe it is a package at all. "Bookdown" is actually a file folder that I reference when exporting some data as a csv file from R as part of a path "C:/users/Documents/Bookdown", but I have every instance of that word commented out in my code and it still will not knit. All of my code chunks run perfectly, but I can't get past this loadNamespace error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think there is a package called as bookdown, and you can maybe just install the package and load the library to ignore this issue. Additionally, please provide at least a glance of your code and the error you getting from it so that it might make more sense for others.

Comment: I tried running install.packages("bookdown") and there is no package called that. I've also searched my code and "bookdown" only appears in commented out areas, so I have no idea why markdown thinks it is a package to install. I don't think my code will help because this error is immediate when knitting, but I have added my set up chunks.

Comment: I might be getting your question wrong but you can try to look at this website to get an idea of the bookdown package (what it is about & how to install & upload it etc. - As a side note, after installing the package and uploading the library to the working space, you might want to restart R as I recall that some unwanted inconveniences might occur in such instances occasionally): https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown I hope this helps because I do not think that there is anything else I can help at the moment with the given information.

Comment: @SamanthaThomas, I have faced this problem a while ago and then opened an [Github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1367). I think it would be quick for you if you discuss your problem in that issue thread also.

Comment: Thank you, this is the same issue I am having! I did download the newest version of RStudio and installed it, but am still having the issue. I will also comment on that other thread